# Starting with $1,9,9,3$ the sequence continues as the last digit of the sum of preceding 4 terms. Will subsequence $7, 3, 6, 7$ ever appear in it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Formally, $a_n = (a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} + a_{n-4})$ mod $10$.
Is there a mathematical way of knowing whether $7, 3, 6, 7$ will ever occur in the sequence?

One idea I was delving upon was to prove the sequence is analogous to a decimal expansion of an irrational number, that way any arbitrary four numbers would appear.

Comment: It's rather the decimal expansion of a rational number (the sequence is periodic).

Comment: This question reminds me of some Ergodic Theory problems that can be solved with Poincare's recurrence lemma. You may want to chech that.

Comment: Thanks @astro, will check it out.

Comment: @DanielFischer I wrote a program to see the next numbers of the sequence, the sequence didn't seem periodic for quite some time. Is there a way to show that the sequence is recurring?

Comment: @hac817 Here's where what you're looking for might be: http://people.dm.unipi.it/dinasso/ULTRABIBLIO/Furstenberg%20-%20Poincare%20recurrence%20and%20number%20theory%20(1981).pdf

Comment: There are only $10^4$ possibilities for the quadruple $(a_{n-1},a_{n-2},a_{n-3},a_{n-4})$. As soon as a quadruple repeats, we have a period. Thus the period is at most $10^4$ numbers long. (You can speed up the finding of the period by considering things modulo $2$ and modulo $5$, then use the Chinese remainder theorem.)

Comment: Note: it is not true that every sequence appears in the decimal expansion of an irrational.  $.101001000100001\cdots$ is irrational, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I did first : if $7,3,6,7$ appeared in the sequence, then continuing the sequence is revealing.

Indeed, we get :
$$
7,3,6,7,3,9,5,4,\color{blue}{1,9,9,3},...
$$

therefore, the sequence $7,3,6,7$ appears, if and only if $1,9,9,3$ appears again.

---

Consider the operation $T :(a,b,c,d) \to (b,c,d,a+b+c+d)$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb Z_{10}$ to $\mathbb Z_{10}$. We basically have to debate if $T^n(1,9,9,3) = (1,9,9,3)$ for some $n$. It is sufficient to show that $T^n$ is the identity map for some $n$.

For this, note that it is enough to show that $T^n$ is the identity map modulo $2$ and $T^m$ is the identity map modulo $5$ for some $n,m$. Then the lcm of $n,m$ provides a candidate power $T^N$ being the identity modulo $10$.

We can use the field polynomial theory at this point. Indeed, note that we have the following :
$$
x^{p^n} - x = \prod_{d | n} \textrm{ (all monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ of degree $d$)}
$$

as polynomials in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ fo any prime $p$ and for any $n$.

Therefore, suppose that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is irreducible modulo $2$ and modulo $5$. From this formula (substituting the matrix $T$ in place of the variable $x$) it follows that $T^{2^4} = T$ modulo $2$ and $T^{5^4} = T$ modulo $5$ (since the characteristic polynomial is monic of degree $4$), and because $T$ is invertible (check!) we get that $T^{15} = I$ modulo $2$ and $T^{624}  = I$ modulo $5$.

It is irreducible modulo $2$ and $5$! Indeed, the characteristic polynomial is $t^4-t^3-t^2-t-1$ , and one can use a standard table of quadratic irreducible polynomials modulo $2$ to verify for $p=2$ and $p=5$ to show that it doesn't have quadratic factors, and simple substitution show no linear factors.

In particular, we must have $T^{3120} = I$ modulo $10$. It follows that $7,3,6,7$ appear in the sequence. You can even find at least one place where they appear.

---

So we saw :

- Working from the sequence $7,3,6,7$ brought the question down to whether the transformation itself was, if raised to a certain power the identity.
- We expressed it as a linear transformations modulo a number, and then modulo a prime , and we looked at its characteristic polynomial modulo these primes.
- A nice irreducible polynomial formula was used, which helped us show that the period in fact exists.

---

EDIT : As Greg points out below, we can make a simpler argument for the recurrence of $(1,9,9,3)$ using backward recursion.

Consider the $10^4+1$ triplets $(a_{n},a_{n+1},a_{n+2},a_{n+3}) , n = 1,2,...,10001$. Two of these must be the same, by the pigeonhole principle. This shows that there exist $T^n(1,9,9,3) = T^m(1,9,9,3)$ for some $n \neq m$. By backward recursion (same as saying that $T$ is invertible), we get that $T^{|n-m|}(1,9,9,3) = (1,9,9,3)$, which shows that $1,9,9,3$ appears again.

Of course, note that this does not provide us with an *explicit* point at which the sequence $7,3,6,7$ appears, which  the other method provides. So you can contrast these methods.

Comment: This is absolutely the right idea, especially the beginning of the post! I wanted to point out that justifying the fact that the sequence is purely periodic is easier: the given recursion $a_n \equiv a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}$ can be transformed into a "backwards recursion: $a_{n-4} \equiv a_n - a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}$. This means that past values are uniquely determined by future values (as well as the usual way around), which (together with the finitely many possible quadruples of values) proves immediately that the starting sequence will repeat.

Comment: @GregMartin I see : there must be a cycle by finiteness, and this cycle must involve the starting value by backward recursion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $X_n = \pmatrix{a_n\cr a_{n+1}\cr a_{n+2}\cr a_{n+3}\cr}$, we have $X_{n+1} = M X_n \mod 10$ where $M = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr}$.  That matrix has characteristic polynomial $P(\lambda) = \lambda^4 - \lambda^3 - \lambda^2 - \lambda - 1$, which is irreducible both mod $2$ and mod $5$.  The period of
$M$ mod $p$ must be a divisor of $p^4-1$.  We find the period mod $2$ is $5$ and the period mod $5$ is $312$.  Therefore the period mod $10$ is $5 \cdot 312 = 1560$.

With $X_0 = \pmatrix{1\cr 9\cr 9\cr 3\cr}$ I find $X_{1552} = \pmatrix{7\cr 3\cr 6\cr 7\cr}$.